# Integrate $\int {{{\left( {\cot x - \tan x} \right)}^2}dx} $

Tags: integration, trigonometry

$\eqalign{
  & \int {{{\left( {\cot x - \tan x} \right)}^2}dx}   \cr 
  &  = {\int {\left( {{{\cos x} \over {\sin x}} - {{\sin x} \over {\cos x}}} \right)} ^2}dx  \cr 
  &  = {\int {\left( {{{{{\cos }^2}x - {{\sin }^2}x} \over {\sin x\cos x}}} \right)} ^2}dx  \cr 
  &  = \int {{{\left( {{{\cos 2x} \over {{1 \over 2}\sin 2x}}} \right)}^2}dx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{{\left( {2\cot 2x} \right)}^2}}   \cr 
  &  = \int {4{{\cot }^2}2xdx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {4\left( {{{\csc }^2}2x - 1} \right)dx}   \cr 
  &  = \int {\left(4{{\csc }^2}2x - 4\right)dx}   \cr 
  &  = 4 \times {{ - 1} \over 2}\cot 2x - 4x + C  \cr 
  &  =  - 2\cot 2x - 4x + C \cr} $

---

Where have I gone wrong? I've tried to spot an error so many times yet I can't find it, I need another pair of eyes.. Thanks.

Comment: everything checks out. You are fine.

Comment: If you have a problem with checking your result against a result returned by a machine like Wolfram Alpha, simply input the difference between the two functions. If it is a constant, then you know the two functions are identical outside the constant of integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think that you've gone wrong? Your answer is correct.

---

**Edit.** To show why the solution is the same as the one in your answers, we just need to show that $\tan x-\cot x=-2\cot 2x$. 
$$
\begin{align*}
&\tan x-\cot x+2\cot 2x \\
&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}+2\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x} \\
&=\frac{2\cos x\cos 2x\sin x-\cos^2 x\sin 2x+\sin^2 x\sin 2x}{\cos x\sin x\sin 2x} \\
&=\frac{2\cos x(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)\sin x-\cos^2 x(2\sin x\cos x)+\sin^2 x(2\sin x\cos x)}{\cos x\sin x\sin 2x} \\
&=\frac{2\cos^3 x\sin x-2\cos x\sin^3 x-2\sin x\cos^3 x+2\cos x\sin^3 x}{\cos x\sin x\sin 2x} \\
&=0
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The answer in the back of this book is: $ - \cot x - 4x + \tan x + c$

Comment: @Assad They are the same solution since $\tan x-\cot x=-2\cot 2x$. Have you tried to show that they are equal?

Comment: Ah I see, I did not realise this... Thanks

Comment: @Assad I've edited my answer with a proof of the equivalence for you as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way could be

$$\int (\cot x-\tan x)^2dx=\int(\cot^2x+\tan^2x-2\cot x\tan x)dx$$

$$=\int (\csc^2x-1+\sec^2x-1-2)dx$$

$$=\int \csc^2x dx+\int \sec^2x dx-4\int dx$$

$$=-(\cot x-\tan x)-4x+C$$

From another answer $\cot x-\tan x=2\cot2x$

Answer (score 1):

$\tan x- \cot x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac{-\cos 2x}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac{-2 \cos2x}{\sin 2x} = -2 \cot2x$

Therefore you answer $-\cot x -4x + \tan x +c$ is correct.