# Integration of a simple trigonometric function

Tags: integration

Considering the following integral:
$$\int(\tan x+\cot x)^{2} d x$$

The following is my solution, which I'm unsure of its correctness as it doesn't quite match the answer Maxima gives.

$$
=\int\left(\frac{1}{\sin x \cos x}\right)^{2} d x=\int\left(\frac{2}{\sin {\left(2x\right)}}\right)^{2} d x \\
=\int\left( 2\csc { \left(2x\right)} \right)^{2} d x = \underbrace {-2\cot u +C }_{u=2x}= -2\cot {\left(2x\right)}+C
$$

Can someone please validate this, and point out my mistake in case my approach is incorrect?

Comment: You've made a mistake in rewriting the integral with the substitution $u = x/2$. You should instead find the integral to be $-4\cot(x/2) + C$

Comment: Your second equality should be: $\frac{1}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac{2}{\sin 2x},\ $ not $\ \frac{1}{\sin x \cos x} = \frac{2}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} $

Comment: @AdamRubinson True, I will never stop making such silly mistakes... I think it should be correct now?

Comment: cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395146/integrate-int-left-cot-x-tan-x-right2dx?rq=1

Comment: By the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dx}\cot(kx) = -k \text{ cosec}^2(kx). $ See if you can spot your final mistake on your own.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Ah true, I'm missing a 2 as I missed accounting the power of two for the 2 inside the parenthesis, thanks.

Comment: I think you should have the right answer now.